# How to use @Service class from another Web App Project

Tags: java, spring, maven, service, dependencies

I'm having a problem right now, I have two Dynamic Web App Project (**ProjectA** and **ProjectB**) and I need to reuse methods from Service class from **ProjectA**. Right now I'm developing **ProjectB**, the methods I need to reuse from **ProjectA** are pulling datas from its own database, and I need to have those data.

I've already done doing this following steps

1. Java Build Path -> Add Project
2. Project Reference -> Add Project

and I also tried to add **ProjectA** jar file as Maven dependency and still not working

In **ProjectB**, I can already import and call methods from **ProjectA** but I'm having a nullPointerException.

ProjectA.java

```
public interface CustomerService {
    public Customer getCustomerDetails(Long id);
}
```

The above class is the class that I need to reuse, for to me have **ProjectA** data.

ProjectB.java

```
public class CustomerController {
   private CustomerService customerService;//service from another project

   public ModelAndView getCustomer(Long id){
     Customer = this.customerService.getCustomerDetails(id);
   }
}
```

Now, In **ProjectB** I need to call CustomerService.class and use its own method for me to have its own data. But unluckily I'm having a NullPointerException everytime call CustomerService interface

Please help I can't get the right thing to do.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't see any Spring annotations, how is `CustomerService ` injected in `CustomerController `

Comment: I already tried to put @Autowired annotation in CustomerService and still not working,

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are not telling Spring to instantiate an object that implements `CustomerService`, for being injected in `CustomerController`. You can do:

1. Annotate the `CustomerService` implementation (`CustomerServiceImpl` in **ProjectA**??) with `@Service`, for tell Spring to instantiate that implementation.
2. Add jar of **ProjectA** in **ProjectB**
3. Tell Spring to scan for beans to instantiate, in xml configuration file: `<context:component-scan base-package="base.package.in.project.a" />`
4. Annotate `customerService` property in `CustomerController` with `@Autowired` for inject the instance of `CustomerServiceImpl` in spring context into this property.